# Server access error for event registration with credit card

Tags: civievent, joomla, stripe

I have a paid event set up for front end registration (Joomla). When "pay later" is used it works fine but when a credit card is used (Stripe processing) the user gets an "Internal server error" message.

Edited to remove all of the logging that was misleading and to add the logging which helped.

In the ConfigAndLog cache

```
Sep 25 21:11:40  [info] $IDS Detector Details = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => mp_52e5e0805583e8a410f1ed50d8e0c049_mixpanel
            [value] => {"distinct_id": "182a8fbd1b8e23-08597f4ac8da3f-1b525635-157188-182a8fbd1b91e3","$device_id": "182a8fbd1b8e23-08597f4ac8da3f-1b525635-157188-182a8fbd1b91e3","$initial_referrer": "$direct","$initial_referring_domain": "$direct"}
            [page] => /index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/ajax/rest&Itemid=484

.....

   [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => IDS_request_uri
            [value] => /index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/ajax/rest&Itemid=484
            [page] => /index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/ajax/rest&Itemid=484
    
    .....
Sep 25 21:11:40  [error] 
$Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
  "message" => "You do not have permission to access this page."
  "code" => null
  "exception" => CRM_Core_Exception {#1613
    -errorData: array:1 [
      "error_code" => 0
    ]
```

Comment: I think the error in the log is a different issue - that one's from a status check and is "correct" in the sense that it's checking that you shouldn't be able to delete arbitrary files. Any other errors listed?

Comment: Well that error is happening every time I try to use a credit card, so it's related although you could be right that it is some secondary consequence.

Comment: Is CiviCRM.ffda733e09f1091580d2e4d0.log owned by root? It should be writable by the web server user. Sometimes cron runs as root or something else and creates the file which then can't be written by the web server, so the log entries that would help troubleshoot this never get written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay there were a lot of distractors but in the end what seemed to solve the server error was to give the public access to ajax via the Joomla ACL settings.